# Use Laravel Auth with custom view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement a one-page application. I want it to resemble the design in the attached image, where the **right box** will host a login/register fragment if the user is not signed in but will update to a profile/logout once authenticated.

[image: Demo]

How can I leverage the existing Laravel authentication feature to get this to work? Something like sending an Ajax request to the AuthController and then return `Auth::user()` in case of login or sending form data to the `auth/register` route.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to check if the user is authenticated or not, then output either the authentication form or a logout button in your template?

Comment: Yes, but I am unsure on how to go about it.

Comment: Let me know if you need further details and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a user is authenticated with

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
}
```

In your template, using [blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade), you could do something like this:

```
@if(Auth::check())
  {{-- Show logout button --}}
@else
  {{-- Show login form --}}
@endif
```

Comment: How are we handling Registration here? Can you elaborate on that please.

Comment: Since that's a rather broad question that depends on your needs and kind of application which I'm not aware of, I suggest that you look into this [tutorial](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/), which explains the new 5.1.4 user login and registration features.